# Simulating process variations

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, nmos

How  to  simulate Drain current vs Drain source voltage  characteristics  of a NMOS with respect to process variations in LT Spice?

Comment: Crudely, the MOSFET current (long channel) is K/2 * W/L * Ve^2. Your process variable is the "K", which is Mu*Cox. Mobility Velocity is part of the Mu.

Answer (score 3):

The usual method for doing this is to use different model files for the transistors. The foundry should be able to supply SPICE models for the "corners of the envelope", which would include three variations of NMOS (fast, typical, slow) and three variations of PMOS (fast, typical, slow).

Combining the fast and slow models for the two types of transistors results in four corner cases. You need to simulate your design at all four corners to make sure it can be manufactured with high yield.

Comment: From where can we get the tsmc model files for nmos (fast,typical,slow) and pmos (fast,typical,slow)?

Comment: You get the models from TSMC. Or, you may be able to get them from www.mosis.com if you execute the proper non-disclosure agreements. It will probably be easier to get models for their older processes, such as 180nm.

Comment: Can you suggest me a link to get these tsmc  models(fast,typical,slow)